# Mongoid `group()` conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I want to provide a condition for my grouping in Mongoid, but how can I send in multiple values for an attribute in the conditions hash? This is what I want to do:

```
PageViews.collection.group(
  cond: {page_id: ['4e6912618083ab383e000010', '4e6912618083ab383e000009']},
  key: 'timestamp',
  initial: {count: 0},
  reduce: "function(x, y) {y.count += x.count;}"
)
```

So therefore any `PageView` with the either `page_id` will be apart of the query, but I can't seem to get the condition hash (`cond`) to work at all! What am I doing wrong here, I'm really confused.

Here is the API docs for the `group()` method: http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#group-instance_method

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**update**

Running the query as such:

```
PageViews.collection.group(
  cond: {page_id: { $in : ['4e6912618083ab383e000010', '4e6912618083ab383e000009']}},
  key: 'timestamp',
  initial: {count: 0},
  reduce: "function(x, y) {y.count += x.count;}"
)
```

Returns the following error, but the syntax looks fine to me:

```
SyntaxError: (irb):170: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC
  cond: {page_id: { $in : ['4e6912618083ab383e000010',...
                         ^
(irb):170: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting $end
...', '4e6912618083ab383e000009']}},
...                               ^
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

It's frustrating that there are like no examples of this anywhere, the docs say that the condition parameter is as such:

> (String, BSON::Code) :cond — default: {} — A document specifying a
>   query for filtering the documents over which the aggregation is run
>   (optional).

So if it takes a `String` or `BSON::Code`, what would this look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `$in` for the query to match against multiple values. So it would be written as

```
PageViews.collection.group(
  :cond => {:page_id => { '$in' => ['4e6912618083ab383e000010', '4e6912618083ab383e000009']}},
  :key => 'timestamp',
  :initial => {count: 0},
  :reduce => "function(x, y) {y.count += x.count;}"
)
```

You can read more about it here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in

Comment: Hmm, seems to give me a syntax error: `(irb):158: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting $end
...', '4e6912618083ab383e000009']}}, ...`

Comment: Did you put the opening bracket between `page_id:` and `$in`?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I updated my question with what happens.

Comment: I've replicated it myself now. Weird - Mongoid must have different syntax to normal Mongo.

Comment: I think I need to provide it as javascript for MongoDB to read, do you know how I can do that?

Comment: I've just edited the answer to change the syntax ( using symbols mapping to values with `=>` ) and this works for me using one of my collections - does it work for you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3285/discussion-between-russell-and-joseph-silvashy)

Comment: Thanks Russell, you were correct on the syntax, but additionally I discovered that I needed to make the ID's `BSON::ObjecId('my_id')` The google group got me all the way there, see here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoid/fcD_EOchUlk